# how to store object with enum field type in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, enumeration

I have following class in my program, i want this class to be stored in oracle 11c database, i know how to store most of the info but how to store usertype which is of type enum? i have following scheme for data model:

[image: here should be picture]

and this is mu user class

```
public class User {

    @Id
    protected Identity<User> id;

    protected String identifier;

    protected UserType type;

    protected String password;

    public static enum UserType {
        CUSTOMER, COURIER;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really man [an object](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#ADOBJ001); or do you want your user table to have a string `type` column that is restricted to those two values; or do you have another table which contains those two values (but may add others) and you want referential integrity between them?

Comment: edited question to specify my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only two fixed values, the simplest way is with [a check constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/datainte.htm#CNCPT1660):

```
create table users (
  id number primary key,
  identifier varchar2(30),
  password raw(64),
  type varchar2(8) not null check (type in ('CUSTOMER', 'COURIER'))
);
```

The `check (type in ('CUSTOMER', 'COURIER'))` is pretty self-explanatory; Oracle checks that the value supplied for that column is one of those two values. Assuming you want it always be set, the `not null` ensures that it can't be left empty.

```
insert into users (id, identifier, password, type)
values (1, 'Bob', null, 'CUSTOMER');

1 row inserted.

insert into users (id, identifier, password, type)
values (2, 'Alice', null, null);

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."USERS"."TYPE")

insert into users (id, identifier, password, type)
values (2, 'Alice', null, 'INVALID');

ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA.SYS_C00113048) violated
```

It would be a bit better to use named constraints:

```
create table users (
  id number,
  identifier varchar2(30),
  password raw(64),
  type varchar2(8) not null,
  constraint users_pk primary key (id),
  constraint users_type_ck check (type in ('CUSTOMER', 'COURIER'))
);
```

More generally, particularly with values that can change, you would have a look-up table and a foreign key relationship:

```
create table user_types (
  id number,
  description varchar2(8),
  constraint user_types_pk primary key (id),
  constraint user_types_desc_uk unique (description)
);

create table users (
  id number,
  identifier varchar2(30),
  password raw(64),
  type_id number not null,
  constraint users_pk primary key (id),
  constraint users_type_fk foreign key (type_id) references user_types(id)
);

insert into user_types (id, description) values (1, 'CUSTOMER');
insert into user_types (id, description) values (2, 'COURIER');

insert into users (id, identifier, password, type_id)
values (1, 'Bob', null, 1);

1 row inserted.

insert into users (id, identifier, password, type_id)
values (2, 'Alice', null, null);

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."USERS"."TYPE_ID")

insert into users (id, identifier, password, type_id)
values (2, 'Alice', null, 3);

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCHEMA.USERS_TYPE_FK) violated - parent key not found
```